# Kmax problem of photo electric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Einstein has a theory in photo electric effect which is hf=hfo + Kmax.Why do some electrons have kinetic energy less than  Kmax?

Comment: Please define the terms, and state your own thoughts. If this is homework tag as such.

Comment: Why shouldn't they have? I don't understand what this question is about, please show a bit more effort to phrase your question in an accessible and understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

The incoming photon produces a photoelectron moving in the same direction as the photon i.e. down into the metal. Photoemission requires the electron to ricochet around inside the metal and either bounce back so it heads out of the metal, or transfer its energy to other electrons so they have enough energy to escape the metal.

This is a highly inefficient process, and only about one photon in 100,000 ends up producing a photoelectron. The process also dissipates energy into the metal lattice, so only a fraction of the original energy ends up with the escaping photoelectron. That's why the photoelectron energies are distributed between zero and $h\nu - \phi$.